# update wpf element before Thread.sleep executes

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I want to know how to refresh a wpf element before Thread.sleep() is executed. In the scenario below the Thread.sleep() call is executed first, then update the wpf element.

I tried this:

In the button_click event handler:

EDIT: To understand what I want, I added some variable assignations and comments.

```
 private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
     //fist of all, set the static variable to_change to true, then Update GUI label
     to_change = true;
     Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateGUI);
     thread.Start();
     //Then sleep 1 second and ( With label changed)
     Thread.Sleep(1000);// one second
     //and lately reset the value of to_change to false and update the GUI again
     to_change = false;
     //UpdateGUI.
 }
```

And in UpdateGUI I have:

```
 private void UpdateGUI()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
                this.label_success.Content = "Successful!"; 
            }
            );
    }
```

Also I've tried with DispatcherPriority.Send which is the highest priority

I guess i'm missing some important concept.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **Never** sleep in the UI thread. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Clements I've edited my question to better understanding. Let me know if you doesn't understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @jberger could be useful if you explain your point.

Comment: @Ecacavelos 1st, what @clemens said. 2nd, you're toggling a boolean value. (if you have some long-running that's supposed to run in the `Click`, then indicate it in the question via `LongRunningCode();`)

Comment: tell us in a more abstract way, what you're trying to do (e.g. `the user clicks a button and I start downloading a file in the background, then I want to show "File Downloaded" when it's complete.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force WPF to process all of the items in its queue by Invoking to the Dispatcher an item that is a lower or equal priority to the task you want to execute.  Just pass an empty delegate as the action, like this.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate { }));
```

This will work; however doing this should not be "normal", and I'm curious why you need to sleep your main UI thread...  The code you show above is scary, but I don't know the big picture, so maybe there is a reason for this?

Comment: Thanks @davisoa. You say it is a bad practice to sleep the main thread?. I want to set a static variable for a period of time to some value and show a message in a label of a window. After that period I want to set to the old value again.

Comment: Then set yourself a DispatcherTimer that ticks after that period and reset the value in the Tick event handler.

Comment: @Ecacavelos the main reason it is bad practice to sleep in the main thread is because the UI will be completely unresponsive for the entire time it is in the sleep call.